# MIC not working while using BSNL 3G USB Datacard

Tags: usb, internet, 3g

I'm using BSNL 3G USB Datacard. While using it in Vista/Ubuntu, if I use some voice chat clients like Skype/Gtalk, the person on the other side isn't able to hear my voice. I couldn't understand the problem with my mic while using USB Datacard. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check in System > Preference > Sound > Input tab, deselect mute option.